# Elasticquent call searchByQuery from Eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Is it possible to call searchByQuery method in Laravel from Eloquent collection like this for example:

```
Table1::with('table2')->searchByQuery()
```

If i call it like this I get an error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::searchByQuery()

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create `scope` [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)

For example, in your model create method

```
public function scopeSearchByQuery($query)
{
    return $query->where('something', '=', true);
}
```

And then, you be able to call this method in your model like `Model::searchByQuery()`

If you need to pass additional parameters to this method you can define it

```
public function scopeSearchByQuery($query, $something = '')
{
    return $query->where('something', '=', $something);
}
```

And call it `Model::searchByQuery('test')`

***Edit: I didn't recognize that you ask about Elastic search package*.**

[Elasticquent docs](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent#setup)

For call this method `searchByQuery` you need to add trait in your model

```
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    use ElasticquentTrait;

}
```

Comment: I suppose you can't call searchByQuery with `with` method, cause `searchByQuery` isn't scope method. `with` return builder which haven't `search...` method

Comment: Do you have an idea how could I join that two tables and call searchByQuery?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's possible